# Regular expression for removing Postgres SQL data insert (COPY) statements.

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, replace, sublimetext

My postgres dump (`pg_dump > file.sql`) contains data that I want to remove. Is there a simple regex (or sed/awk command) to delete all the lines between a particular `COPY table_name` statement and the termination word (".").  I know regex's aren't ideal for NOT matches and multi-line patterns, but I tried these anyway (in sublime find/replace):

```
"COPY ((?!\\[.])*.*)*"

"COPY ((?!\\[.]$)*(.[\n])*)*"

"COPY (?!\\[.]$)(.*[\n]*)*"
```

The closest I can get is to match the first line of data after the copy statement:

```
"COPY (?!\\[.]$).*[\n]+.*[\n]+"
```

Comment: Why not exclude table data from dump with `pg_dump` params?

Comment: Didn't know it was possible to exclude table data without also excluding the table schema. Guess I should RTD a bit more and see if some combination of `--schema-only` and "--data-only" and table exclusions would do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you probably want to do as follows (note this poses some issues with foreign key dependencies in some cases:

```
pg_dump -s mydatabase > dump.sql
pg_dump -a -t table_i_want1 -t table_i_want2 -t table_i_want3 >> dump.sql
```

The -s flag means `--schema-only` and the -a flag tells it to "append" (i.e. data only).

Comment: Yea, thanks for the explicit answer. That's what I was looking for. So will foreign keys fail on reload of this dump?

Comment: Specify your -t tables in an order so that they don't fail.  It is up to you to manage that order in this case.  In my tests these were done in inverse order.  In 9.2 and higher, you may find --section=data to be better, and you could in fact dump all three sections separately and reload possibly omitting the data if you like, and that would solve the problem too (since fkeys would be created after you load the data in that case).

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the investigation and testing.